# How to replace all except first 10 elements matched with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I use the following code to remove all text elements like `<00:10:12>` from the given text:

```
f_lrc = open(file_, 'r')
lyrics = f_lrc.read()
lyrics = re.sub(ur'<\d{1,2}:\d{2}\.\d{1,2}>', '', lyrics)
```

Is there any way to keep such elements in the first 10 lines of the text file? Or, just keep first 10 elements matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice your file , but you need use `readlines()`:

```
lines =f_lrc.readlines()
lyrics = lines[10:]
first_part = lines[:10]
yrics = re.sub(ur'<\d{1,2}:\d{2}\.\d{1,2}>', '', '\n'.join(lyrics))
last = '\n'.join(first_part) + yrics
```

if you have read your line before you can split by `\n` and apply your regex :

```
f=f_lrc.split('\n')
lyrics = f[10:]
first_part = f[:10]
yrics = re.sub(ur'<\d{1,2}:\d{2}\.\d{1,2}>', '', '\n'.join(lyrics))
last = '\n'.join(first_part) + yrics
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I do the same without reading the file with `readlines()`? The file has been already read (for some other processing), I would prefer not to read it again.

Comment: Thanks. I should apply regex to `'\n'.join(lyrics)`, since it doesn't work with list `f` directly. And the last line should also convert `first_part` to string.

Comment: @LA_  you're welcome , yes , i missed that , ;) fixed

Comment: Looks like you also identify `first_part` (first 10 lines incorrectly) - it should be `f[:10]`, not `f[:-10]` (which returns everything except first 10 lines?).

Comment: @LA_ oops , just a typo , sorry im very Busy now!